# Data content not rendering on the webpage: Server not replying back

Tags: php, qcodo

My page is made in php, I have qcodo which is layered on top of my database for the website.
Occasionally, the webpage does not render and instead of the content it should display it displays the website URL in the body.  This problem started occurring after I added few fields in the database.  At first I thought this might be a qcodo problem, so I tried qcube on a test page but the problem was not fixed.

Can anyone point me to right direction, I think it is the server that is not sending a sent content message to the client.

Comment: Firstly, I think we're gonna need to see some source for the page you're having problems with.  Secondly, have you tried a "View source" on the resulting page to see if there's anything else in there?

Answer (score 0):

No errors? Try to turn on error and warnings.

If the error is not consistent then it could be your web/db server is busy.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, something very similar happened to me long time ago. It ended up it was due to an empty line that was somehow appended to one of my .php files.